# Classification with neural network in matlab: get probability of element belonging to i-th class

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, supervised-learning

I would like to solve a classification problem with Matlab. I have a dataset consisting of 3 classes and 1900 samples. Each sample is defined by 10 features and I have 900 samples for class '1', 500 for class '2' and 500 for class '3'.

I tried to use the standard `patternnet` tool in Matlab to train a neural network. I made different test with different number of neurons, from 1 to 100 but I always get bad performances for the classification.

So I took a look to the confusion matrix and I noticed that the problem is that the classifier is confusing classes '2' and '3'. What I tried next is create two neural networks:

1. The first neural network is a 2-classes classifier, with class '1' and class '23' (the union of classes '2' and '3'). This first classification has a good accuracy for me (around 90%)
2. The second neural network is again a 2-classes classifier which takes as input only elements of class '2' and '3'. The problem is that the accuracy of this second neural network is quite poor, around 55%.

So again I have some difficulties to improve the classification accuracy. I would like to make some test to see if I can improve the accuracy.
My idea is to see what is the probability of each element to belong to a specific class.  What I would like to do then is one of the following:

1. Try to change the threshold value which determines the class of a sample. This would work if for example, all the elements that have a probability > 70% of being class '3' are really class '3' but if the probability is between 50% and 70% this elements are generally class '2' (I am just making up number to try to explain what I would like to test)
2. Create a class '4' for samples that are to difficult to be classified. Again this would work if, for example elements that have a probability > 70% of being class '3' are really class '3' and I will consider class '4' elements with probability <70%. If this work I could have some elements that are "unknown class '4' " but elements classified as '2' or '3' would be correct with an high degree of accuracy

So first I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the probability of each element to belong to a specific class and second if there is a standard method in Matlab to implement one of the two test that I would like to do. (Of course if someone has a better idea I am glad to test it)
Sorry for the long description but I hope at least I explained what is my problem.

Comment: Do you really have to use a neural network? With the SVMs this task is rather easy :/

Comment: Also, it is ok `patternet()` as training function. But how did you evaluate the output and accuracy so far?

Comment: The accuracy for me is just `(Number of samples correctly classified)/(Total number of samples)`. The dataset is divided in 70% training, 15% Validation and 15%Test and there not significative differences between Validation and Test accuracy

Comment: Yessir, the accuracy definition is fine. However my main question is how did you evaluate the output (i.e. by means of which function)?

Comment: @Akessiox I am not constrained to use neural network, but I have no idea of how to use SVMs, if you think it is really simple can you send me a link to an example?

Comment: The performances are evaluated by `perform(net,TrueClass,Output)` where `net` is the trained network, `TrueClass` contains the true Class of the problem and `Output` is computed by `Output = net(x)`

Comment: As my knowledge, though, `Output=net(x)` does not give the predicted labels and the performances returned by `perform` is not the accuracy. PS: I have added an answer with a complete SVM implementation

Comment: Yes sorry you are right, there is another step `OutputInd= vec2ind(Output)` which takes the index of the maximum value of Output which is compared with the  `TrueClassInd= vec2ind(TrueClass)` and the accuracy is `sum(TrueClassInd~= OutputInd)/numel(TrueClassInd)`

Comment: If `TrueClass` contains the true labels (i.e. values 1, 2 and 3) there's no need for the `vec2ind()` function. Also in the accuracy you shouldn't put `~=`, in this manner you're evaluating the error rate, not the accuracy. you should take into account the correctly predicted labels. Try doing `accuracy=sum(TrueClass==OutputInd)/numel(TrueClass)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MeSS83. In order for me to provide a proper example (with codes and everything) I had to write an entire answer. The easiest way to perform this multi-class classification with SVMs is by using *LibSVM*. LibSVM is a free SVMs library (you can download it [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/libsvm.cgi?%20http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm%20zip)), that can also be installed and used in Matlab environment. Unzip the file, there is a matlab folder in which you'll find the installation guide and everything.

Basically what you want to do is the One-vs-All SVM approach, that is you train N SVMs (where N is the number of classes) and each SVM is trained to separate a given class *i* from all the others (the *i*-th class will be positive and all *not-i* classes will be negative). Let's say `TrainingSet`, `TrainingLabels`, `ValidationSet`, `ValidationLabels` are your dataset (their names are rather straightforward) and `numLabels` is the number of labels (3 in your case).

You can train these SVMs as follows:

```
for k=1:numLabels
    % k-th class positive, all the other classes are negative
    LabelsRecoded(TrainingLabels==k)=1;
    LabelsRecoded(TrainingLabels~=k)=-1;

    model{k} = svmtrain(LabelsRecoded, TrainingSet, '-c 1 -b 1 -t 0');
end
```

In this code `'-c 1 -b 1 -t 0'` are LibSVM parameters for the SVM: *c* is the regulatization term (set as 1), *-b 1* means that you want to gather also the output probabilities (a.k.a decision values) and `-t 0` means you are using a linear kernel. More infos can be found in the readme inside the LibSVM package.  As instead, `model` is a cell array in which the k-th element contains the structure regarding the SVM trained to separate the k-th class from all the others.

The prediction phase has the following structure:

```
LabelsRecoded=[]; % get rid of the results stored previously in the training phase
for k=1:numLabels
    # same as before, but with validation labels
    LabelsRecoded(ValidationLabels==k)=1;
    LabelsRecoded(ValidationLabels~=k)=-1;

    [~,~,p] = svmpredict(LabelsRecoded, ValidationSet, model{k}, '-b 1');
    prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);
end
```

Inside `prob` you'll have 3 columns (3 is the number of classes) containing the probability of the k-th class being positive (mind the `model{k}.Label==1`).  Now you can gather the predicted labels according to the maximum probability value as follows:

```
[~,PredictedLabels] = max(prob,[],2);
```

Now you have both the Predicted Labels and the Validation Labels and you can evaluate the accuracy according to the standard formula.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer I will test it as fast as I can

Comment: Just a curiosity, what are the benefits of SVM with respect to neural networks? I am just asking because I am quite new to the subject and I do not know anything about SVM

Comment: Well, with the SVMs you have very few parameters to configure: the *c* parameter (as in the code) and the kernel parameters. In case of linear kernel, the kernel function is a dot product so you don't need to configure any parameters...but more accurate kernel functions such as polynomial or Gaussian/RBF have very few parameters (the standard deviation, in the gaussian case and the polynomial coefficients in the polynomial case). As instead, with Neural Networks you have loads of parameters (bias and weights): the more neurones, the more parameters.

Comment: Also, there is an optimality process involved (the SVMs, in poor terms, aim at looking for the *best* hyperplane that separates your classes). I kindly suggest you to read how the Sequential Full Optimization algorithm works (by J. Pratt). Such algorithm is used (in LibSVM as well) to train SVMs and the global optimum is guaranteed. That is not true with Neural Networks. NN, also, are more prone to overfitting (i.e. if the training set is not good or if the training phase is very long, the system tends to learn characteristics proper of the training set and they loose in generalization).